# Import from barrel files TypeScript/Yarn v4 monorepo

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, yarn-workspaces

I'm working on a small monorepo project, using Yarn 4 workspaces with TypeScript. I've mostly got it working, but I've hit an edge(ish) case with some import paths.

I have a common library in this repo with the following `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@example/common",
  "exports": {
    "./*": {
      "default": "./lib/*.js",
      "types": "./lib/*.d.js"
    }
  },
}
```

This project builds its source code to the project's `lib` folder.

In my other projects, I've added `"@example/common": "workspace:*"` as a dependency. This allows me to import any named modules under common. For example, common contains `src/utils.ts`. This builds a matching `lib/utils.js` file (with corresponding type declarations), and I can import it like so:

```js
import { doSomething } from '@example/common/utils'
```

This is great as I don't need any custom TS paths - it "just works" with the normal resolution algorithm and I get the correct imports during runtime, and the correct typings when editing/compiling.

However, with this setup, I'm *not* able to import from folders with barrel files (`index.js`) in them implicitly. If common contains `src/utils/stuff.ts`, and a `src/utils/index.ts` file that re-exports the stuff module's imports, I can't do this:

```js
import { somethingFromStuff } from '@example/common/utils'
```

I have to explicitly import `@example/common/utils/index`, and then I might as well not have it.

#### Question

Is there any way to configure the export mappings so that I keep the existing working behavior (being able to import `utils.ts` by importing from `@example/common/utils`) while also being able to import `stuff/index.ts` by importing from `@example/common/stuff` (implicitly picking up the index file)? I'd prefer to avoid custom TS paths if possible.

I have both `"module"` and `"moduleResolution"` set to `"node16"` in my TS config if that's relevant.

Comment: Barrel files are mostly an anti pattern. One reason is they make imports less specific which is what you are bumping into with your given directory structure and exports definition. Try adding an entry like this first in your exports: `"./barrel": "./lib/utils/index.js"`. Then `import { stuff } from "@example/common/barrel"`.

Comment: I don't disagree, but this is a monorepo with a bunch of legacy where they are heavily used, so I'd rather support them and gradually rewrite than change all of the files and imports. Your solution would work but I'm looking for a wildcard way of supporting them - I'd have to add hundreds of explicit exports otherwise.

Comment: If you care about the code base then you’re better off doing the needed work.